# Вывод списка данных по текущему дню в таблицу

Tags: python, django

```
def _get_SR_list(self):
    list= []
    current_user = self.request.user
    act = ServiceRequest.objects.filter(owned_by=current_user).order_by("started")
    list = act.all()
    return list
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как бы мне к моей переменной started подцепить фильтр на текущий день (вывод всех сущностей по сегодняшнему дню, если таковые имеются)

Answer (score 0):

```
ServiceRequest.objects.filter(owned_by=current_user, started=datetime.date.today()).order_by("started")
```